# ngx-international-phone-number to cant added style

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, ngx-international-phone-number

Im used my angular project for this [**ngx-international-phone-number**](https://github.com/nikhiln/ngx-international-phone-number), I tried to add style, but its not worked for me, anyone know how to add correctly **css** on this input

*Look my image, button and input filed is not aligned*

[image]

[**StackBlitz here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zlx3sw)

```
<international-phone-number class="mystyle form-control form-control-sm"  placeholder="Enter phone number" [maxlength]="20" [defaultCountry]="'us'"  name="phone_number" [allowedCountries]="['in', 'ca', 'us']"></international-phone-number>
```

**css**

```
.mystyle .dropbtn {
  background: #2196f3;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}



 .mystyle .form-control {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 0.4375rem 0;
   font-size: 1rem;
   line-height: 1.5;    margin: 0px 5px;
   color: #495057;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
   background-clip: padding-box;
   border: none;
   border-radius: 0;
   box-shadow: none;
   transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add `:host ::ng-deep { *your css* }` before your style.
And change `app.component.css > app.component.scss`
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-add-style 
Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-phone-number instead of ngx-international-phone-number, its basically an extension of ngx-international-phone-number but its updated and well maintained with language support and issues fixed quickly upon feedback. Flag issues is also fixed here.
Here is the link of library https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-phone-number